# Why doesn't the spacebar within a div with contentEditable enabled work within a mat-expansion-panel-header?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This was working within my app before I updated to Angular 11, and now it just refuses to work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hh81uk?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <div contenteditable="true">Hello</div>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header
    #panelHeader
    (keydown.space)="panelHeader._toggle();"
  >
    <div contenteditable="true">Div</div>
    <span contenteditable="true">Span</span>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I thought it may have been something to do with using `$event.stopImmediatePropagation()` or `$event.preventDefault`, but as you can see in the stackblitz example I am not using either of those functions and still when I press spacebar a whitespace character is not added to the content editable div or span.

However as soon as I try on the div located within the mat-expansion-panel, the spacebar works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well doing "space" is intended to open close the panel. They prevent default, that's for sure. In order to not open/close panel, you need to stop the event propagation from the content editable in the panel:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <div contenteditable="true">Hello</div>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header #panelHeader>
    <div (keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation()">
      <div contenteditable="true">Div</div>
      <br />
      <span contenteditable="true">Span</span>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hh81uk-haezrt?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

Comment: So why does using stopPropagation allow the space character to be inserted? Is it because stopPropagation prevents the event from bubbling but also allows the default to happen, which is to insert the whitespace character?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The event does not reach the expansion panel listener and therefore the  expansion panel does not prevent default on it.